# Multiplying digits inside numbers based on position of digit

Tags: sort, numeric-data

I have list of numbers like this:

```
0987656787689
2345453326780
3453212332345
1324532449876
1234532444568
3245321343456
1324354532376
1234532153457
```

I would like to sort the numbers based on the results of multiplication of digits in positions sixth and seventh, so the results are like this:

```
3245321343456
3453212332345
1234532153457
1234532444568
1324532449876
2345453326780
1324354532376
0987656787689
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{ print substr($0,6,1)*substr($0,7,1) }' <file
30
15
2
6
6
2
20
6
```

Sorting the original numbers based on the the above result (this was a followup question [in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475321/multiply-digits-inside-numbers-based-on-poition-of-digit/475324#comment868286_475322)):

```
$ awk '{ print substr($0,6,1)*substr($0,7,1) }' <file | paste - file | sort -n | cut -f 2
3245321343456
3453212332345
1234532153457
1234532444568
1324532449876
2345453326780
1324354532376
0987656787689
```

This pastes the result of the multiplication together with the original numbers as two separate tab-delimited columns, then sorts it numerically and extracts the second column (the original numbers).

Comment: thank you very much this is stunning I spent three days on this ;(

Comment: @Koran Yes, asking followup questions is generally frowned upon.  The question should be complete from the start.  If you keep adding to it or changing it, you will invalidate given answers, and people will just be confused when trying to follow what's going on.

Comment: @Goro I did update the question. sorry about confusion thank you

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -F// -lane 'print $F[5] * $F[6]' < file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits each line into the @F array
- `-F` tells how to split
- `//` means to split everywhere, i.e. into single characters
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to output

Comment: thank you very much for the quick response! Appreciated! I have one last question please, how can I sort the numbers based on the multiplication of the digits in positions 6 and 7?

Comment: To ask a new question, create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk, for its flexible sorting ability:

```
function compare_product(i1, v1, i2, v2) {
  return substr(v1, 6, 1) * substr(v1, 7, 1) - \
         substr(v2, 6, 1) * substr(v2, 7, 1);
}

BEGIN {
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="compare_product";
}

{
  elements[NR]=$0
}

END {
  asort(elements, sorted_elements, "compare_product");
  for (element in sorted_elements) {
    print sorted_elements[element];
  }
}
```

This requires keeping the entire contents in memory, and also -- due to its simple implementation -- recomputes the products more than it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this simple `mawk` (no internal sort) approach (that may benefit from some polishing):

```
awk  '{print $6 * $7, $0 | ("sort -n > TMP" )} END {close ("TMP"); FS = " "; while (1 == getline < "TMP") print $2}' FS="" file
3245321343456
3453212332345
1234532153457
1234532444568
1324532449876
2345453326780
1324354532376
0987656787689
```